# How to Edit Wordpress' Admin Page of Post Listing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking to add a mini form to a post type's listing page (edit.php) in the admin page for the post type. See the below image for a visual example of where I'd like to add a custom form to the page.

[image]

The closest I've been able to get an action hook (trying not to modify Wordpress' core!) is to attach a hook to **admin_notices**, which would put my custom form within the *Updated!* banner you see at the top of the image, but that's not an ideal solution.

Is there a hook or a method I'm missing to accomplish what I'm doing?

Comment: prob not that specific, but did you think about jquery to add it in?

Comment: I did, a while back. would be an alright solution i think, and will likely do this (thanks). always worth check if it's possible to do it direct through your custom theme in PHP, IMO.

Comment: true, most of the hooks are here for reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference there is also a tutorial here for listing all the hooks on a admin page, http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-get-the-current-screens-hooks--wp-26891

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'll have a look. I didn't find any hooks relating to this before I submitted the question, but I'll give it a second look. Thanks for your help, I'll likely go the javascript generation approach after all.